# Update whole table with concatenated strings in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

as the title says, in ms access, i´d like to update my whole table with concatenated strings that need to be inserted into a certain column.

example:

string=ice

columnA | columnB

berg | iceberg

bomb | icebomb

blob | iceblob

so you see, i need to concatenate my string and columnA in order to insert all that into column b.

i tried

UPDATE mytable SET mytable.columnb = "ice" & [mytable].[columna];

but it does not work, meaning there are no results in the cells. there are no errors visible. also tried with CONCAT but did not work either.
could you please assist?

Comment: Logic/syntax  looks correct. are you getting an error or it just doesn't achieve the desired results?  have you open and closed the relevant table/query to ensure it's not just a refresh problem?

Comment: did you use double-quotes around "ice"? Or, single-quote 'ice' ... should be single-quotes.

Comment: In Access SQL, both double- and single-quotes are valid. If table and field names are correct, the UPDATE statement should work.

Comment: "does not work" is not a sufficient description of the problem. Please [edit] your question to describe what actually does happen. ... error message? ... unexpected results? ... nothing at all?

Comment: Results are empty cells, no error message

Comment: I suggest you post your **actual** UPDATE sql, I doubt your columns are `columna` and `columnb`. Add some sample input data, and the actual result after the UPDATE (which columns are empty?). Otherwise we can't help you.